# Node.js Request Stream Pipe Rename Filename

Tags: node.js, request

I am using Node.js Request module to server file form remote server to user Browser .

Here is code i use :

```
expressjs_app.get("/file_url", function(req, res){
   request.get('remote_file_url').pipe(res);
});
```

Everything works fine , I just want know it possible to change filename for user in Browser ?

**Update**

I sending remote file to user for download , i want when user want save file there is be different name other than orginal file name.

For example if remote file is: `http:// domain.com/file1.zip` i want change filename to `http:// mydomain.com/myfile.zip`

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you need to rename the file from a browser? Or do you need to pass a filename to the get?

Comment: @Michelem I sending remote file to user for download , i want when user want save file there is be different name other than orginal file name. for example if  remote file is : domain.com/file1.zip i want change it to mydomain.com/myfile.zip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a header in the response:

```
expressjs_app.get("/file_url", function(req, res){
   res.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="new file name.pdf"');
   request.get('remote_file_url').pipe(res);
});
```

Easy enough. Good luck.

Comment: thank its work , except download links form subscene.com not work example download link : `subscene.com/subtitle/download?mac=GbtlYOZoHuXhdzEjY4vd2cN7lDHHWIpZarWcT4l_j0Qinf7vwBHRBektYIfhg5G30`

Comment: I'm guessing they are checking cookies or referrer. There is no easy solution to that. Please mark the question as the answer if it helped.

Comment: this didnt change the name of the file. Any suggestions ?