# Node wrapper API for a different Download API

Tags: node.js, api, express, download

I am trying to write a wrapper API for a different API which takes filename as input and downloads the file.

The raw api is
https://test.com/?filename=abc.pdf

I want to write a wrapper for this above API, but that doesn't seems to be working, it just prints some data which I cant read but doesnot send the file.

```
  var options = {
    "method": "GET",
    "hostname": test.com,
    "port": 443,
    "path": "/?filename=" +fileName,
    "rejectUnauthorized": false,
  }

apiHelper.makeRequest(https, options, false, function(responseObject){
    if(responseObject.error){
      downloadBackupCallback(null, responseObject.error);
    }
    else{
      downloadBackupCallback(responseObject.data, null);
    }
  })
```

Can any one please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're piping through the body of the response from the API verbatim, but not setting the correct request headers.

When accessing your wrapper script from a browser, this will have the result of attempting to render the response of the request as if it were HTML. When this happens with a PDF file it can look a lot like garbage.

Ensure you are setting the correct HTTP headers when sending back your response, and if possible, take these from the headers provided by the API you are wrapping.

I would suggest you need, at minimum, `Content-Type` and [`Content-Disposition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138271/node-js-request-stream-pipe-rename-filename#answer-32139857). Ideally use a stream-based solution to pass though the response as it comes in, so that you're not caching a large amount of data locally if the files are particularly large.

Comment: if possible can you please refer me an example link. Meanwhile I am also trying what you suggested.

Comment: An example of what? An example of any particular element of my proposed solution would probably be found by perusing [the express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.methods). Me finding or generating an example of the whole thing would effectively be doing your homework for you... I did find that `sendFile()` needs to have a file on disk to send, so I will remove that part of my answer, as it would be more optimal to send the response directly through.